# Visual Studio Publish Profile Publishes Wrong Build Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm trying to automate deploying a Web Api 2 project with Visual Studio 2013. I've made a publish profile named "Test" shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
    This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
    by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
    -->
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        <LastUsedPlatform>x86</LastUsedPlatform>
        <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
        <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
        <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
        <publishUrl>C:\DbServiceDeploy</publishUrl>
        <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>
    </Project>
```

Even though it has the line <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration> it seems like Visual Studio is publishing my debug build. I'm calling msbuild like so

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" C:\somefolder\Myproj.csproj /p:
DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Test
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This excellent blog post led me to find the answer https://sedodream.com/2012/10/27/msbuild-how-to-set-the-configuration-property . I'll summarize in case the link dies: when a build is kicked off MsBuild evaluates the properties once and uses that value for the remainder of the build. Since the Configuration property was resolving to Debug MsBuild was using that as the Configuration to publish.

TLDR;

Pass the configuration on the command line, add

/p:Configuration=Release

to the command line call

Comment: The <LastUsedBuildConfiguration> element is used by Visual Studio to set the build configuration before launching a build & publish within the IDE.  But on the command line, you do have to specify it manually.

Comment: Correct, it's just for the Visual Studio UI. That's why we named it LastUsedBuildConfiguration instead of Configuration :)

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi A comment at the top of the publish profile detailing this quirk would have saved me a lot of time, please consider adding it

Comment: @reggaeguitar I thought there was a link pointing to more info about how to automate publishing, which includes that info and more.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi I did read that webpage but it wasn't clear that I had to pass in the Configuration property. Thanks for actually responding though, I've seen you on some MVA courses and really like your manner of teaching.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi I've created a publish profile in VS2015, We have created a configuration "ReleaseX64" to build 64 bit DLL, I've selected "ReleaseX64" for my publish profile. When I publish from VS2015 everything works great, however when I use commanLine, it publishes Debug/x86 DLLs. 
msbuild myProj.csproj /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<profile-name>
I tried to pass  
 /p:Configuration=ReleaseX64 , it gave me error saying configuration does not exist, can some help me here?